# Pandas: sum strings with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
member_id   event_path  event_duration
111 vk.com  2
111 vk.com  3
111 facebook.com    1
111 facebook.com    4
111 facebook.com    20
```

And if `event_path[i] == event_path[i-1]` and `event_duration < 5`, I need to concat string.
I use

```
df = df.groupby(['member_id', 'event_path'],
                sort=False,
                as_index=False)['event_duration'].sum().where(df['event_duration'] < 5)
```

but it returns

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Desire output

```
111 vk.com  5
111 facebook.com    5
111 facebook.com    20
```

Comment: when you state `event_duration < 5` - is this when the row and its previous sum to less than 5, or when the row itself contains a value less than 5? If, for example, the final row had a value of 2, would `facebook.com` become one row of total 7?

Comment: @asongtoruin when value in string less than 5

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear from your question, but I assume that for each member and path combination, you want to sum all values less than 5? If so, we can do this by separating out the values above and below 5, then summing those below 5 and merging the two frames we get as a result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'member_id': [111, 111, 111, 111, 111],
                   'event_path': ['vk.com', 'vk.com', 'facebook.com', 'facebook.com', 'facebook.com'],
                   'event_duration': [2, 3, 1, 4, 20]
                   })

sums = df[df['event_duration'] < 5].groupby(['event_path', 'member_id'], as_index=False).sum()
large = df[df['event_duration'] >= 5]

final = pd.concat([sums, large])

print final
```

prints out:

```
   event_duration    event_path  member_id
0               5  facebook.com        111
1               5        vk.com        111
4              20  facebook.com        111
```

Comment: I tried to test it on big file and I lost some data. Value in event_duration is less than before sum

Comment: @PetrPetrov Hmm, it shouldn't be. Can you provide an example of where this is occurring?